# variable size ioctl for configuration parameters

Tags: c, linux, driver, linux-device-driver, ioctl

I need to pass variable-sized configuration to the char device/driver and I am wondering what is the best way of going about it. Currently, I use a structure with fixed array sizes similar to this:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE1    4
#define ARRAY_SIZE2    4
#define ARRAY_SIZE3    32
#define ARRAY_SIZE4    8
#define ARRAY_SIZE5    8
    
typedef struct
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            uint64_t item1        :   4;
            uint64_t item2        :   4;
            uint64_t item3        :   8;
            uint64_t item4        :   48;
        };
        
        uint64_t combined;
    };
        
    union
    {
        uint64 array1[ARRAY_SIZE4];
        uint64 array2[ARRAY_SIZE5];
        uint64 array3[ARRAY_SIZE4];
    };
} B;
    
typedef struct
{
    uint64 element1;
    uint64 element2[ARRAY_SIZE1];        
    B element3[ARRAY_SIZE2];
    uint64 element4[ARRAY_SIZE3];
    
} A;

#define IOCTL_XYZ _IOWR(MAJOR_NUMBER, 10, A)
```

But I do not want to be limited by the array sizes (especially for element 3).
Should I break this down into multiple ioctls for each element of struct A? But that would result in multiples ioctl calls. Or replace fixed arrays with size and pointers? I have read it's not good practice to include pointers inside struct elements (If someone can elaborate why), then what's the best practice for this scenario?

Keeping in mind that I need this structure to be common for windows and linux driver.

Comment: If `element3` needs to be variable length, that cannot be done as a C `struct` type unless it is the last member of the `struct` type. The size _can_ be encoded in the ioctl command number but `_IOWR` uses the size of the last argument so cannot be variable. If you want to encode the variable size in the ioctl command number at runtime, you would need to use `_IOC()` or something. Putting the size in the ioctl command number is recommended practice, but not required (unless going through a specific kernel framework that requires it). You could store a length in the `struct` instead.

Comment: I have used pointers in structures passed to ioctls before.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a great example or not, but "spidev" ioctls are one place where pointers are used. `struct spi_ioc_transfer` in "include/uapi/linux/spi/spidev.h" holds pointers as `__u64` so it is the same size on architectures that support both 64-bit and "32-bit compatible" pointers. But the 32-bit compatibility code in "drivers/spi/spidev.c" still needs to be careful to convert pointers from 32-bit to 64-bit correctly (see the `#ifdef CONFIG_COMPAT` parts of the driver). It is also an example where the ioctl command code encodes a variable size since it handles an array of structs.